# Is there a format to store (and recover) a numpy array that is accessible/compatible with tools outside the Python ecosystem?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, compatibility

My team is implementing a database to store machine learning datasets.
Currently, we compress *numeric numpy arrays* (as reshaped 1-dimensional arrays) using lz+zstd; and, compress *numpy arrays containing string values* (as objects) using _pickle+lz+zstd.

We are a bit worried about the compatibility of such storage choices and wondering if it would be easily accessible by Java/Scala, C/C++ or other eventual clients (Julia, R) that could share the same information.

**Is the raw binary info inside a numpy array universal in this sense, or just arbitrary?**

ps. The choice of combining two compressors was made after speed vs space benchmarks.

Answer (score 1):

According to [numpy.lib.format](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.html#module-numpy.lib.format)

> The .npy format is the standard binary file format in NumPy for
> persisting a single arbitrary NumPy array on disk. The format stores
> all of the shape and dtype information necessary to reconstruct the
> array correctly even on another machine with a different architecture.
> The format is designed to be as simple as possible while achieving its
> limited goals.

So, numpy array format is universal and stable.

And to my knowledge, C++, Julia, and R all have libraries that can read numpy files.